# Why is isNaN('-10') false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, isnan

Just curious as to why `isNaN('-10')` is false?  I was thinking `isNaN('-10')` should be true, but `isNaN(-10)` should be false?

Does Javascript try to convert strings to numbers before applying `isNaN`?

Comment: Documentation FTW!

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+isNaN%28string%29) of [Why is isNaN(“1”) false?](/q/21177042/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNaN` implicitly converts to Number type. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior)

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior):

> Since the very earliest versions of the isNaN function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN.